# Example of Orthogonal set in $\mathbb R^d$ of Cardinality $2d$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Please how do I give an example of an almost orthogonal set in $\mathbb R^d$ of cardinality $2d$.

I know by definition that a set of vectors $\{u_1, \dots, u_n \}$ is an orthogonal set if each pair of distinct vectors from the set is
orthogonal. That is, if $\langle u_i, u_j \rangle = 0$  whenever $i \neq j$. But how do I give an example as stated in the problem above? Any help or hint is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by almost orthogonal ?

Comment: @pmun From study I got that, If we have a large integer $n$ and some small $\epsilon >0$. In $\mathbb R^n$ a large family of vectors $(u_i)_{i=1}^{k}$ is almost orthogonal in the sense that $|(u_i | u_j)|<\epsilon$ when $i \neq j$

Answer (score 1):

There is a notion of almost orthogonality that is : A subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is almost orthogonal if for any triple in $A$, at least two elements are orthogonal.
For example, if $B=\{e_1,\dots,e_d\}$ is the canonical orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $A=\{e_1,2e_1,\dots,e_d,2e_d\}$ is almost orthogonal in that sense.

Now, multiplying each vector of $A$ by $\epsilon/3$ gives you an almost $\epsilon-$orthogonal set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ in your sense of cardinality $2d$.